# Edit deep object value by property

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object

```
let a = {b : {c : "d"}}
```

And i have the property who must change with a new value

```
let prop = "b.c";
let newValue = "e";
```

So, in my object, the "c" must be edited with the new value.

i tried

```
a[prop] = newValue; // but it create "b.c" property

let fields = prop.split('.');
a[fields] = newValue; // but it create "b,c" property

// all i want is a dynamic way to do
a[fields[0]][fields[1]] = newValue;
```

is it possible ?

thanks

Comment: `{b : c : {"d"}}` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Is your object meant to be `let a = {b : {c : "d"}}`?

Comment: My bad, i edited

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: `let newValue : "e";` is invalid syntax aswell btw.

Comment: Your best bet would using something like [`_.set` from Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set). The alternative is to re-implement this functionality. That's not *hard* but it depends on how much error handling you want to do and how much syntax you want to support. Lodash already has both of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `reduce()`

```js
let a = {b : {c : "d"}}

let prop = "b.c"
let newValue = "e"

prop.split('.').reduce((a, o) =>
  Object(a[o]) === a[o] ? a[o] : a[o] = newValue
, a)

console.log(a)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the thing i was looking for. a way mor simply has the question marked as duplicate